# How to get all post from subcategory in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress question.
i want display first 5 category from subcategory.

for example

Main category : Festival
Subcategory : IndependencedayDay

so in my single post i want to display first 5 post 
from Independenceday's category

i write code myself but it display wrong post. 
i want to diplay subcategory's post.

i want to display independenceday's post tell me

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=$catnamelike&showposts=5'); ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="umaylike">
<table width="287" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

          <?php the_title(); ?>  

          </a>  </h3>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
global $post;
$cat_ID=array();
$categories = get_the_category(); //get all categories for this post
  foreach($categories as $category) {
    array_push($cat_ID,$category->cat_ID);
  }
  $args = array(
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'category__in' => $cat_ID
  ); // post__not_in will exclude the post we are displaying
    $cat_posts = get_posts($args);
if ($cat_posts) {
  foreach ($cat_posts as $cat_post) {
    ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($cat_post->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($cat_post->ID); ?></a><br />
    <?php
  }
}
?>
```

Note that this is more targeted towards having one category.